# HERE API Fleet Telematrics search timeout issue

Tags: javascript, api, here-api, here-maps-rest, here-fleet-telematics

''Couldn't reach way point 61 due to search timeout''

I am passing 66 waypoints (all in one city) with ;sort to get optimized route. But 6 coordinates cause this issue. If I remove those 6 coordinates I get route. But interesting part is that if I use those 6 coordinates with few other (less then 15-20) other coordinates it also returns route. But if I use at least one of those 6 with all others it get's me this issue. Also all coordinates are real, close to road, real addresses.
Anyone had similar experience or does anyone have some tips or solution to this problem?

url:

https://fleet.ls.hereapi.com/2/calculateroute.json?driver_cost=10&mode=fastest;car&apikey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&waypoint0=26.28435464,50.66609614&waypoint1=26.28354691,50.66660475;sort&waypoint2=26.28365760,50.66729720;sort&waypoint3=26.28300850,50.67023948;sort&waypoint4=26.28420433,50.66883098;sort&waypoint5=26.28480910,50.66964790;sort&waypoint6=26.28524086,50.66912216;sort&waypoint7=26.28476347,50.67000680;sort&waypoint8=26.28525136,50.67006078;sort&waypoint9=26.28565090,50.67102560;sort&waypoint10=26.28538838,50.67151906;sort&waypoint11=26.28546181,50.67206564;sort&waypoint12=26.28641037,50.67139447;sort&waypoint13=26.28664951,50.67096278;sort&waypoint14=26.28725490,50.66798743;sort&waypoint15=26.28601064,50.66605126;sort&waypoint16=26.28587181,50.66453207;sort&waypoint17=26.28829740,50.66525650;sort&waypoint18=26.28835769,50.66516772;sort&waypoint19=26.28880213,50.66828758;sort&waypoint20=26.28933175,50.66765249;sort&waypoint21=26.29071799,50.66837427;sort&waypoint22=26.29047578,50.66462576;sort&waypoint23=26.29154600,50.66407620;sort&waypoint24=26.21900607,50.58650687;sort&waypoint25=26.28538838,50.67151906;sort&waypoint26=26.28565090,50.67102560;sort&waypoint27=26.30043171,50.66140831;sort&waypoint28=26.27487289,50.67261694;sort&waypoint29=26.29704576,50.66347105;sort&waypoint30=26.29295116,50.66598915;sort&waypoint31=26.26899440,50.67699120;sort&waypoint32=26.28354691,50.66660475;sort&waypoint33=26.28933340,50.66765410;sort&waypoint34=26.29883209,50.65907657;sort&waypoint35=26.29154594,50.66407643;sort&waypoint36=26.27282930,50.66923155;sort&waypoint37=26.27306630,50.66934220;sort&waypoint38=26.28880213,50.66828758;sort&waypoint39=26.29241254,50.66866770;sort&waypoint40=26.27461814,50.67238616;sort&waypoint41=26.29687716,50.66764486;sort&waypoint42=26.28835769,50.66516772;sort&waypoint43=26.29800729,50.66936374;sort&waypoint44=26.29028945,50.67419440;sort&waypoint45=26.28480910,50.66964790;sort&waypoint46=26.29666130,50.65842569;sort&waypoint47=26.28435464,50.66609614;sort&waypoint48=26.28546181,50.67206564;sort&waypoint49=26.29848258,50.66208736;sort&waypoint50=26.28833090,50.65991560;sort&waypoint51=26.29879847,50.65897150;sort&waypoint52=26.29483552,50.65967523;sort&waypoint53=26.28587181,50.66453207;sort&waypoint54=26.29384799,50.66423309;sort&waypoint55=26.28525136,50.67006078;sort&waypoint56=26.28641299,50.67142059;sort&waypoint57=26.29909413,50.65938893;sort&waypoint58=26.28476347,50.67000680;sort&waypoint59=26.28365760,50.66729720;sort&waypoint60=26.28524086,50.66912216;sort&waypoint61=26.29652180,50.66269719;sort&waypoint62=26.28641037,50.67139447;sort&waypoint63=26.28829769,50.66525660;sort&waypoint64=26.28725490,50.66798743;sort&waypoint65=26.28300850,50.67023948;sort&waypoint66=26.26944969,50.67688331;sort&waypoint67=26.29239901,50.66865161;sort&waypoint68=26.28933175,50.66765249;sort&waypoint69=26.26920910,50.67701430;sort&waypoint70=26.29794056,50.66247046;sort&waypoint71=26.29844976,50.65887384;sort&waypoint72=26.29048574,50.66465447;sort&waypoint73=26.28829740,50.66525650;sort&waypoint74=26.29047578,50.66462576;sort&waypoint75=26.29154600,50.66407620;sort&waypoint76=26.28480910,50.66964790;sort&waypoint77=26.29774430,50.66970080;sort&waypoint78=26.28933340,50.66765410;sort&waypoint79=26.28601064,50.66605126;sort&waypoint80=26.29298637,50.66598248;sort&waypoint81=26.28420433,50.66883098;sort&waypoint82=26.29666130,50.65842569;sort&waypoint83=26.28365760,50.66729720;sort&waypoint84=26.29071799,50.66837427;sort&waypoint85=26.29298637,50.66597342;sort&waypoint86=26.28664951,50.67096278;sort&waypoint87=26.29730176,50.66319460;sort&waypoint88=26.28829740,50.66525650;sort&waypoint89=26.29474720,50.66185758;sort&waypoint90=26.21900607,50.58650687

Comment: Hi, Do you using Freemium account or Paid ?

Comment: Hi, I am using Freemium.

Comment: Please share your entire query for us to investigate.

Comment: Ok. I added complete url to the issue above. Looking forward for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the sort mode in Fleet Telematics API normal calculate route request, there is a timeout of 50 - 60 sec. Also you are using upto 90 waypoint in sort mode, which is quite expensive computation wise with the strict timeout. So it could be expected that the calculation hits the timeout.

Please use Waypoint Sequence Extension API, which has higher timeout and a different algorithm.